# Clion missing some obvious templates like if, switch

Tags: c, clion

When I type "for" and press TAB, a full for loop is created as expected but this is not the case for "if" "elif" "switch" keywords as I am used to other IDEs. Am I expected to implement these by myself on CLion or can I find a internet source for all these done beforehand?

Comment: What would you expect for `if`? A pair of braces?

Comment: C has no `elif`. In C you are expected to implement pretty much everything not in a library. But I can see the advantage of expanding `switch` where a framework with one `case` and the `default` are written.

Comment: @WeatherVane `#elif`? :-)

Comment: A decent text editor like [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) can do this sort of thing for you.

Comment: @melpomene `elif` is not a C "keyword", `#elif` is a preprocessor instruction.

Comment: @WeatherVane CLion is a fancy IDE for C, from JetBrains, the folks behind PhpStorm, WebStorm, PyCharm, etc.

Comment: @EugeneSh. sthg like this...  if (true)
{

}

Comment: @WeatherVane sorry I made a mistake. I meant "else"